# clickonce ftp publishing denied for policy reasons

Tags: ftp, clickonce, visual-studio-2017

I can't get Visual Studio 2017 publish a Winforms application through ClickOnce to my new ftp server with IIS 10/Windows 2016.
Both anonymous and basic authentications are enabled in the server, authorisation is read+write for all users.

I can post a file successfully from a Filezilla client, but publishing to same folder with Visual Studio throws next error:

Failed to connect to 'ftp://ftp.myftpserver.com/myfolder/' with the following error: Unable to create the Web site 'ftp://ftp.myftpserver.com/myfolder'.  Request denied for policy reasons.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

If you require to use FTPS I got it to work by explicitly stating ftps://IPOFFTPORDOMAIN in Server: field of Publish window Profile. I found this tutorial from one of the hosting providers: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/a2-hosting-products/windows-hosting/publish-a-site-from-visual-studio-using-ftps

Answer (score 2):

Removing SSL request from FTP server did the job.

It seems VS2017 cannot publish through FTPS

Comment: I have the same problem, how can I remove remove SSL request from FTP server?

Comment: On IIS 7, select your ftp site, open SSL Ftp settings and check "Allow SSL" instead of "Require SSL"